# Listing of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to list the last 1 hour files which has `.sh` extension.
I am currently using the following:

`ls -l *.sh | find "/root/" -mmin -60 | awk '{print $9}'`

However this command isn't working as expected.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a `find` command to do this:

```
find <DIR> -type f -name '*.sh' -mmin -60
```

or

```
find <DIR> -type f -name '*.sh' -mmin -60 -executable
```

**Explanations:**

1. `<DIR>` is the target directory where you want to search
2. `-type f` to force to look for files
3. `-name '*.sh'` to look for files with the sh extension
4. `-mmin -60` to look for files that have been modified in less than 1 hour
5. `-executable` if you want to add the constraint that the file have execution permission.
6. `-maxdepth 1` to look only for files in  folder or use a higher depth if you want to look until N levels. You command becomes: `find <DIR> -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' -mmin -60 -executable`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
find . -name "*.sh" -mmin -60 -ls | awk '{print $9}'
1
1
```

The $9 then gives me the day of month.

A similar result is possible, purely by gnu-find:

```
find . -name "*.sh" -mmin -60 -printf "%Ad\n"
01
01
```

except for the leading zeros. There are 3 dates possible:

```
%Ak    File's last access time in the format specified by k, which is either `@' or a directive for the C `strftime' function.  The possible values for k
                 are listed below; some of them might not be available on all systems, due to differences in `strftime' between systems.
%Ck    File's last status change time in the format specified by k, which is the same as for %A.
%Tk    File's last modification time in the format specified by k, which is the same as for %A.
```

(from the manpage of gnu-find).

Comment: Thank you ,it was useful